# MySQL joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I got 2 tables with almost same structure:

table `products`:

```
-----------------------------
ID | OrderNo | Name   | Size
-----------------------------
1  | 1000    | TShirt | S
-----------------------------
```

table `variants`:
(Relationship: `variants`.`MasterID` = `products`.`ID`)

```
-------------------------------
ID | MasterID | OrderNo | Size
-------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1001    | M
-------------------------------
2  | 1        | 1002    | L
-------------------------------
```

Now I need to get the following result:
(I need every row from `products` and every row from `variants`)

```
1000 | TShirt | S
------------------
1001 | TShirt | M
------------------
1002 | TShirt | L
...
```

I was trying it like this:

```
SELECT p.OrderNo, p.Name, p.Size FROM products p
UNION
SELECT v.OrderNo, p.Name, v.Size FROM variants v
```

Is there a better way to do this?
The result is correct but a bit slow (13000 rows in `products` and 5000 rows in `variants`).

Comment: Is `1000 | Tshirt | S` a typo? There is no `1000` in products or variants table.

Comment: Yes, changed it. Sorry, my fault

Comment: What's the relationship between both tables?

Comment: `variants`.`MasterID` = `products`.`ID`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.OrderNo, p.Name, v.Size 
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN variants v
ON v.MasterID = p.ID
```

should do it. You may want an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN; not clear from your question.

Comment: as u can see there is a field `size` in the `products` table as well. In your example, i only get the `size` from variants.

Comment: Is the products Size field always S, or is it predictable in some way?